# how to stop jquery accordion - onclick opening all accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am trying to make an accordion but it open all item when click how to stop all and apply only the item clicked.

[JSfiDDle](https://jsfiddle.net/rupomkhondaker/57cLga3y/)

```js
$("#toggle>h4.vpm-tab-index").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if ($('#toggle>div.vpm-content-tab').hasClass("closed")) {
    $("#toggle>div.vpm-content-tab").css("display", "block");
    $("#toggle>div.vpm-content-tab").removeClass('closed');
    $("#toggle>div.vpm-content-tab").addClass('opened');
  } else {
    $("#toggle>div.vpm-content-tab").removeClass('opened');
    $("#toggle>div.vpm-content-tab").addClass('closed');
    $("#toggle>div.vpm-content-tab").css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

```css
.vpm-tab-index {
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.vpm-tab-index:before {
  content: "\f067";
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-family: fontawesome;
}

.vpm-content-tab {
  background: #f9f8f8;
  padding: 11px;
  margin-top: -11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggle" class="toggle">
  <h4 class="vpm-tab-index tab-opened"><span class="icon-minus-sign"></span> Quick Info</h4>
  <div class="vpm-content-tab closed" style="display: none;">
    <p>Quite possibly the best customer service I have ever received from an online retailer.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="toggle" class="toggle">
  <h4 class="vpm-tab-index tab-opened"><span class="icon-minus-sign"></span> Quick Info</h4>
  <div class="vpm-content-tab closed" style="display: none;">
    <p>Quite possibly the best customer service I have ever received from an online retailer.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `$(this).siblings('.vpm-content-tab')` instead of `$('#toggle>div.vpm-content-tab')` inside click event listener. Exception to this line: `$("#toggle>div.vpm-content-tab").removeClass('opened');`

Comment: @Developer107 works on second iten but first item not closed

Comment: Replace `$("#toggle>div.vpm-content-tab").removeClass('opened')` with `$("#toggle>div.vpm-content-tab").removeClass('opened').css("display","none");`

Comment: As a side note - it's bad practice to have multiple elements with the same ID, and you wouldn't have this problem if you had unique IDs and referred to them in your JS by reference.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/57cLga3y/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's not valid to use the same id (`#toggle`) for more than one element.
2. You set the class for **all** the `div.vpm-content-tab` elements while you need to set it only on the next `tab`.

Like this:

(Notice that you can chaining jQuery method just like I do in the example, read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp)

```js
$(".toggle>h4.vpm-tab-index").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var tab = $(this).next();
  if (tab.hasClass("closed")) {
    tab.show().removeClass('closed').addClass('opened');
  } else {
    tab.hide().addClass('closed').remove('opened');
  }
});
```

```css
.vpm-tab-index {
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.vpm-tab-index:before {
  content: "\f067";
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-family: fontawesome;
}

.vpm-content-tab {
  background: #f9f8f8;
  padding: 11px;
  margin-top: -11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle">
  <h4 class="vpm-tab-index tab-opened"><span class="icon-minus-sign"></span> Quick Info</h4>
  <div class="vpm-content-tab closed" style="display: none;">
    <p>Quite possibly the best customer service I have ever received from an online retailer.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="toggle">
  <h4 class="vpm-tab-index tab-opened"><span class="icon-minus-sign"></span> Quick Info</h4>
  <div class="vpm-content-tab closed" style="display: none;">
    <p>Quite possibly the best customer service I have ever received from an online retailer.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also need to toggle this class`tab-opened` to `tab-closed`